# Vue + TypeScript app is showing a blank white page

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to follow along with a paid course to learn Vue + Firestore, but adpat it to use TypeScript instead of plain JavaScript.

I have gone through the basic setup, but my app is blank. The local host home page should be showing some simple header text from within the `App.vue` file. But it's just a white blank page.

Here is [the full repo](https://github.com/BenJackGill/vue-chat).

And here is the `App.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header>
      <h1>Vue Voxer</h1>
      <p>Realtime Walkie-Talkie Voice Chat</p>
    </header>

    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: {},
});
</script>

<style>
header {
  text-align: center;
}
button,
input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Good catch! I was relying on Eslint and Typescript errors, but console (which I forgot to check) had an error from the Firestore plugin. I have removed that and now it's working. Will debug the plugin seperatley now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a note on vuefire's [document](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/)

> Note: This version currently supports Vue 2 and Firebase 7. Support
> for Vue 3 / Composition API and Firebase 8 is on the way.

You are using Vue3 so you must install the correct version of vuefire

```
npm install vuefire@next firebase@next
```